# Programmatically select text in UITextView, in layout manager which has multiple text containers

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview, nslayoutmanager

If there is only one TextContainer in the layout manager then OS will be handling the User interactions. But with multiple text containers in place, I read somewhere that its not out of the box.

Here are some the things that I have already used with no luck.

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(5, 10);

UITextPosition *from = [textView positionFromPosition:[textView beginningOfDocument] offset:range.location];
UITextPosition *to = [textView positionFromPosition:from offset:range.length];
[textView select:self];
[textView setSelectedTextRange:[textView textRangeFromPosition:from toPosition:to]];
```

And

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(5, 10);
textView.selectedRange = range;
```

I am able to get it working if there is only one TextContainer, but I want it with multiple containers.

This is what I wanted to achieve programatically[image]

UPDATE:
Added the code that I am working on

```
- (void)didDoubleTap:(id)sender {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
            if (tapGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
                CGPoint point = [tapGesture locationInView:self];
                for (UITextView *textView in self.textViews) {
                    if (CGRectContainsPoint(textView.frame, point)) {
                        textView.selectable = YES;
                        [textView becomeFirstResponder];
                        NSInteger glypIndex = [self.articleLayoutManager glyphIndexForPoint:point inTextContainer:textView.textContainer];
                        NSLog(@"GlyphIndex : %ld",glypIndex);
                        NSRange wordRange = [self rangeForWordWithGlyphAtIndex:glypIndex];
                        wordRange.length += 5;//For testing purpose
                        NSLog(@"Got Range");
                        UITextPosition *beginning = textView.beginningOfDocument;
                        UITextPosition *start = [textView positionFromPosition:beginning offset:wordRange.location];
                        UITextPosition *end = [textView positionFromPosition:start offset:wordRange.length];
                        UITextRange *textRange = [textView textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end];

                        textView.selectedTextRange = textRange;
                        textView.selectedRange = wordRange;
                        UITextRange *textRange1 = [textView selectedTextRange];
                        CGRect wordRect = [self.articleLayoutManager boundingRectForGlyphRange:wordRange inTextContainer:textView.textContainer];
                        NSLog(@"Got Word Rect");
                        UIMenuController *theMenu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
                        [theMenu setTargetRect:wordRect inView:textView];
                        [theMenu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: In your code you're using the _textView_ outlet, did you try to declare all your text views the same way, calling them (for example) _textView1_,_textView2_,_textView3_, then apply your code on those outlets ? (i.e. textView3.selectedRange = range;)

Comment: I am not using any Outlet, but saving all the textViews in an array. Based on User tap I am selecting the textView and trying to add code which selects the text.

Comment: Any :sender reference on your tap method that would allow you to target the proper textView ?

Comment: I have added few gesture recognizers, based on the gesture point I am comparing with the frames of textview's in the array that I am saving and selecting the right textView. Even then its not working.
I am starting to think, its not possible to select the text in programmatically if there are multiple textContainers. Because, my code starts working as soon as I layout all the text in a single container.

Comment: You should post some code: how do you attach tap-detection on your textviews, and the method called on tap... Because as is it's not easy to figure out what can happen

Comment: I have added the code that is being called on tap detection. Point is working fine as I am able to present the MenuViewController without any issue. Thanks.